# Servlet --x--> Ajax: Ajax code not receiving servlet response

Tags: ajax, servlets, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

I'm unable to figure out what is going on here in this ultra simple example.

**Problem Summary:** I have a simple servlet that appears to run just fine if I drive it manually... by issuing its URL from the browser. By 'just fine' I mean: I can see in the browser HTML page whatever I write in the servlet response.

*However*, if I issue the very same URL via Ajax code, the servlet processes the request fine and even 'appears' to be writing out the response fine ... but, just that I do not see any response on the Ajax client code side and thus neither in my browser HTML page.

*Further*, if I make my XHR request syncrhonous, the browser error console shows the following exception:

*Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///home/sd/Desktop/test.html :: callServlet :: line 35"  data: no]*

**Environment:**

Browser: Firefox 3.5.3

Servlet container: Tomcat 6.0.20

OS: Linux / Fedora 11

**Ajax code:**

```
<!-- test.html -->
<html>
<head>
  <script>
var req;

function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function servletCallback() {
  var field = $("debugHtmlId");
  field.innerHTML += "readyState='" + req.readyState + "'<br> ";
  field.innerHTML += "status='" + req.status + "'<br> ";
  field.innerHTML += "responseText='" + req.responseText + "' | <br> ";
}

req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = servletCallback;

    function callServlet() {
      // With async mode off, I get the
      // Exception listed above.
      //    req.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/aaa/bbb?f=test", false);

      req.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/aaa/bbb?f=test", true);
      req.send(null);

    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>    
  <input id="callserv" type="submit" value="Call Servlet" onclick="callServlet();" />
  <span id="debugHtmlId"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Servlet code:**

```
// servlet code
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

    rsp.setContentType("text/html");

    String val = req.getParameter("f");
    if(val.equals("test")) {
      // Increment value.
      ++_count;

      // Return value.
      PrintWriter out = rsp.getWriter();
      out.printf("%d\n", _count);
      out.close();

      // This shows up fine in servlet log.
      System.out.printf("%d\n", _count);
    }
  }

  // This variable is incremented and returned on each call to doGet().
  private int _count = 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

1. Including the result: Here's what I see for example as the value of my innerHTML of my debugHtmlId element.

   readyState='1'
   readyState='1'
   readyState='2'
   status='0'
   responseText='' |
   readyState='4'
   status='0'
   responseText='' |
2. Strange behavior: Notice also that my readystatechange handler is getting **re-entered**! I mean, I was expecting to see readyState='...' status='...' responseText='...' triads for every state change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was:
I had loaded the above HTML in my browser not from the Tomcat/web server but from my local file system. I thought, for development I won't need to deploy the HTML to the server.

Since what I originally wanted works fine now, I'm not so worried now about the exception I was getting in the sync mode of ajax.

Comment: Regarding the exception you were getting - Firefox does indeed give this error whenever sync mode is used for Ajax calls because sending a sync request blocks the execution and waits for the reply thus making the UI unresponsive to the user. So practically there is no meaningful use-case scenario for a sync Ajax request. However, other browsers like IE/Chrome/etc. allow this behavior without throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

I was working through this same problem. It's definitely a cross domain issue and in my case the javascript file was the same server as the servlet and i was downloading and and calling the script from an html page that was not. Just like Harry I was loading the html locally and getting a 0  status.

The solution for me was to add

resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

to the SERVLET code - this allows the javascript to call the servlet from outside the domain.  It was killing me since i knew the servlet was getting hit, the server debugger was logging the GET - but the response was empty and the status was 0.  all of the code on the question will work fine, if you add that header to the servlets response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Don't call `out.close();` on the `PrintWriter`. Instead, call `out.flush();`.

Comment: Had tried it already, never worked. In fact, I read somewhere that we're supposed to use close() and not flush()... otherwise, the ajax side remains under the impression that more stuff is on the way. That was the reason, I replaced flush() with close().

Answer (score 0):

I look at the code and did two things to work on my CentOS 5 Linux dev box with Tomcat5:

1. Modified the code and rename my servlet to eServlet:

   ```
   req.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/aaa/bbb?f=test", true);
   ```

   to

   ```
   req.open("GET", "eServelet?f=test", true);
   ```
2. Modified     WEB-INF/web.xml and added servlet mapping

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>eServletApps</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>eServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>eServletApps</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/eServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
3. Compiled with command:

   ```
   # javac -classpath $CATALINA_HOME/common/lib/servlet-api.jar eServlet.java
   ```
4. Loaded it and it Works without any problems